# Remove Memory From a Program

Tags: windows, memory, c++

Say you have program.exe that is taking up 100kb of your memory. Are you able to reduce it to 0kb so it theoretically can't run? Taskmgr.exe may say that it is running, but if it's reduced to 0kb, then it's functions can't be followed out.

Then with that, if a program reached 0kb, would it even be listed under taskmgr?

[EDIT] I was assuming a situation where the traditional taskkill or C++ equivilent (forgot. I'm relearning C++) is blocked and won't work.

[EDIT 2] My script is just a simple batch script. It basically looks like this:

```
@echo off
:x
taskkill /f /im program.exe
goto x
```

Comment: I'm curious: what exactly does your script do? Would you be comfortable posting it somewhere? (If it's small, you can put it in your question; if it's significantly large, use some pastebin.)

Comment: One question: why?

Comment: I'm relearning C++. I haven't learned memory allocation yet. My school blocks task manager and I need it sometimes when our old computers start to slow down a lot. I haven't tried a standalone task manager yet, but I can do it from the command line. They don't block command.com

Anyway, I was trying to think of an alternative way to shutdown a program than conventional means.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you somehow managed to get the kernel to forcibly deallocate memory that had already been given to the program, it would probably just crash whenever it tried to access that memory. Such a thing is very likely unsupported: programs shouldn't have to keep checking to see if the memory they were *granted* is still theirs to use, and it would be awfully hard for a program to function in such an environment anyway.

Any *well-written* program will *check* to see if heap allocations were successful before trying to use them. If one was denied, the program can detect this (in C, `malloc()` will return a null pointer) and choose how to handle it (e.g., it might print an error message and exit, or it might keep trying to get the memory). In order to know what your restrictive program would do if it couldn't get any memory, we would need access to either extensive documentation, or its source code.

Let's say the kernel does this anyway. It allocates a chunk of memory to program `foo`, which uses it to store some data. After a while, the kernel steals the memory back, possibly reallocating it to some other program (or even the operating system). How is `foo` supposed to get its data now? If it tries to access the chunk of memory that used to have its data, the system should kill it—and rightly so! The memory might now contain another user's sensitive data, in which case allowing `foo` to read it would be a security hole. If it's allocated to a program running as another user or to the operating system, allowing `foo` to write to it could result in any number of bad and unpredictable things happening.

Of course, there are also variables stored on the stack. I've never heard of a way to check if *those* allocations were successful; everything seems to just assume they were. I would *guess* that each program automatically gets some minimal amount of memory to play with; if that memory weren't available, the system would refuse to start the program.

Comment: what is the kernel reallocated the memory to another process and the application tried to write to it?  You could break another program you are running, or even the OS.

Comment: @Keltari I've edited my answer to explain this. You're absolutely right. This is exactly why systems should never allow programs to read or write other programs' memory.

Comment: I didn't realize you could screw up the OS. When you say break a program, are you referring to it crashing?

Comment: It might crash. What happens depends on everything that's going on; where the program is in its execution, the exact modifications made to its memory, and the timing of everything. If the memory were simply deallocated with no warning, the program would crash if it later tried to use that memory. If the system allowed the memory to be arbitrarily overwritten, an attacker could overwrite the memory of a program running as `root` and gain root access.

Answer (score -2):

Not really. I'm not very familiar with the architecture of Windows, but on Unix, you're looking for the `renice` command. This reduces (or increases) the priority with which the process is allocated CPU time. For example, at a niceness value of -20, the program is allocated all possible CPU time, whereas at +20, it would only run if no other process needed the CPU.

(If you want the process to take zero CPU time, you can forcibly suspend it by sending the `SIGSTOP` signal via the `kill -STOP` command, and resume it with `SIGCONT` using `kill -CONT`.)

Comment: -1: `renice` reduces a process' scheduling time; it doesn't affect memory allocations.

Comment: I know... re-read my answer please...

Comment: Yes? I downvoted it because it talks about only CPU time, not memory.

Comment: What he's asking not being possible, I tried to provide a roughly equivalent solution that would have a similar effect. I guess it's not what he's looking for...

Comment: It's not possible with existing kernels (as far as I know). One might be able to patch that functionality into Linux.

Comment: While I'm sure your thought is appreciated, I interpret the question as being specifically memory-related, rather than a more general “How can I halt the execution of an already-running program, without outright killing it?” (which has likely already been asked and answered).